# Correctly interpret newline characters

Tags: bash, cat, xargs

I have a file which I need to parse, word by word, and make changes to only certain words. My bash script works in everything but retaining newline characters. I have constructed a minimum example as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# contents of myscript.sh

toks=( $* )

for tok in ${toks[*]}; do
    # make changes to $tok if need be
    printf "$tok "
done
```

I hope to use it as follows:

`cat filename.txt | xargs myscript.sh`

where filename.txt may look like

```
word1 word2
word3
```

The expected output would be the same as input, in this case, but I just get

```
word1 word2 word3
```

Comment: Quote your variables. Quote them. Also don't use `$*` when you want the positional arguments safely use `"$@"`.

Comment: if you've accurately expressed your need, then I take issue with your implementation.  You don't really need to go word by word, right?  Just use an extended regex with a word boundary match.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about `"$@"` - I am using `toks=( "$@" )` now and getting the same result. As far as going word by word, I may not need to do that, but this is how I started it. My intent is to write a command which will take in any number of arguments and change *only* words matching a certain pattern to an integer of a specific nature. I had started it by looking at each word independently and changing it if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -ra line; do
  for tok in "${line[@]}"; do
    # make changes to $tok if need be
    printf "%s " "$tok"
  done
  echo
done
```

Comment: And invoke it with `cat filename.txt | myscript.sh`  (or `myscript.sh < filename.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

What about a regex instead of tokenizing?

```
$ echo -e "word1 word2
word3" | perl -pe 's/\bword[12]\b/wordX/g'
wordX wordX
word3
```

Granted this needs perl, but there are alternative implementations of PCRE.